# OSX, android emulator, Xamarin = No disk space

Tags: android, macos, xamarin, android-developer-api

I've been developing w/ Xamarin on OSX for a few weeks now and I'm constantly running out of disk space on a 256 gig ssd with pretty much no other apps installed. I ran Daisy Disk and it's indicating there's a folder called ".android" taking up 143 gigs of space! I can't find this folder (hidden I assume) and I need that space back, at least part of it. Can anyone:

- Tell me what this folder is
- What I'm doing wrong that this folder is using 143 gigs and advise how to fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am *assuming* it is loaded full of `Android System Images`:

```
>cd ~/.android/avd

foobar:avd sushi$ ls -l
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  9 sushi  staff  306 Aug  7 07:30 api22.avd
-rw-r--r--  1 sushi  staff  105 Aug  6 17:56 api22.ini
drwxr-xr-x  8 sushi  staff  272 Aug  6 17:47 api23.avd
-rw-r--r--  1 sushi  staff  105 Aug  6 17:33 api23.ini
drwxr-xr-x  8 sushi  staff  272 Aug  6 16:10 foo.avd
-rw-r--r--  1 sushi  staff  101 Aug  2 04:26 foo.ini
```

Each `XXX.avd` directory will contain a copy of the Qemu system image for the Android device, snapshots of the runtime image, etc...

Open up your Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager and remove all the unneeded virtual devices that you have created:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I only had 4 of them I wasn't using, but deleting those 4 freed up 105 gigs of space! I'll be more judicious in creating AVDs from now on.